# How to set integer counter format for file name in logback to 3 digits?

Tags: java, logging, logback

It is possible to set the name of the log file generated by logback so that the archive files are numbered in the following way: Test.2022-09-23.001.log instead of Test.2022-09-23.1.log? It is about the numbering, which is the archive file on a given day, to number 001.002 ... instead of 1, 2 ... "% i" is responsible for this place, there is no mention in the documentation and changing this parameter to another one, and the change to "%iii" causes a compile error and change to "%03i" but does not work. Does anyone know if there is such a possibility? It is a file name given in the fileNamePattern tag

```
<appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>Test.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>Test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
       <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>    
       <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
       <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not supported by default.

file name is created by the [FileNamePattern](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/helper/FileNamePattern.java) class .

it not supports to custom file name,because the access level of FileNamePattern member variable  is default(means only package).

There is a less recommend way to implement,use **reflect** to replace member variable.

```java
public class CustomIntegerTokenConverter extends IntegerTokenConverter {
  //convert integer to string with 3 digits
  @Override
  public String convert(int i) {
    return String.format("%03d",1);
  }
}
```

```java
public class SimpleTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy<E> extends SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy<E> {

  //use reflect to replace member variable of FileNamePattern.
  @Override
  public void start() {
    super.start();
    try {
      Field triggeringPolicyField  = TimeBasedRollingPolicy.class.getDeclaredField("timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy");
      triggeringPolicyField.setAccessible(true);
      TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy triggeringPolicy = (TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy) triggeringPolicyField.get(this);
      triggeringPolicy.setTimeBasedRollingPolicy(this);


      Field fileNamePatternField  = RollingPolicyBase.class.getDeclaredField("fileNamePattern");
      fileNamePatternField.setAccessible(true);
      SimpleFileNamePattern SimpleFileNamePattern = new SimpleFileNamePattern(fileNamePatternStr, this.context);
      fileNamePatternField.set(this,SimpleFileNamePattern);

      Field fileNamePatternWCSField  = TimeBasedRollingPolicy.class.getDeclaredField("fileNamePatternWithoutCompSuffix");
      fileNamePatternWCSField.setAccessible(true);
      SimpleFileNamePattern SimpleFileNamePatternWCS = new SimpleFileNamePattern(
          Compressor.computeFileNameStrWithoutCompSuffix(fileNamePatternStr, compressionMode), this.context);
      fileNamePatternWCSField.set(this,SimpleFileNamePatternWCS);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

```java
public class SimpleFileNamePattern extends FileNamePattern {
  public SimpleFileNamePattern(String patternArg, Context contextArg) {
    super(patternArg, contextArg);
  }
  
  // replace to a custom integer converter 
  static {
    try {
      Field field = FileNamePattern.class.getDeclaredField("CONVERTER_MAP");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) field.get(SimpleFileNamePattern.class);
      map.clear();
      map.put(IntegerTokenConverter.CONVERTER_KEY, CustomIntegerTokenConverter.class.getName());
      map.put(DateTokenConverter.CONVERTER_KEY, DateTokenConverter.class.getName());

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

```xml
<appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="SimpleTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>Test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
       <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>    
       <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
       <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

[image]